# How to use the info panel in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, measurement

I would like to use the "info" panel in illustrator to have infos such as :

- the distance of the top of an object to the top of the artboard it belongs to;
- the distance of the left border of an object to the left border of the artboard it belongs to.

**How can I easily achieve that?**

This pictures shows what I want:
[image]

Comment: This sort of automatic data reading functionality in relation to the artboard is not possible in Illustrator.

Comment: That's a shame...

Comment: Illustrator does have ruers and a ruler tool.

Comment: How can I use them to have a precise measurement?

Comment: Some crazy person voted to close as "unclear what you're asking", without even bothering to ask for a clarification. That's crazy, it couldn't be clearer what this question is asking. Is someone voting to close at random?!

Comment: I found the answer. Some people like the power they find on such communities sites. That's by the way why I left the French Wikipedia community...

Answer (score 2):

This should help! 
(at least it works on my system)

[image]

Comment: Hey, you're right! For me (on CS6) this only works when rulers are visible (`view > show rulers`), but with rulers visible, it does switch the info panel to use the **currently selected** artboard, which is the last one clicked on.